# How to edit structure values after passing them c

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct

Hello guys i just want to read the students from a file and then ask the user to add a new student but first I have to add it to my structur and I don't really kmow how to edite or add students to my allocated structure. Please learn me how to send the values of my struct to any other function and edite them..

```
struct student {
    char personnummer[11];
    char förnamn[11];
    char efternamn[10];
    char gender[7];
    char programmdife[20];
    char age[4];
    char email[30];
    //struct likaprogramms *likaprogramm;
} *personer;

void f(struct student **x)
{
    char str[200];
    int j=0;
    struct student *personer = (struct student*)malloc(j * sizeof(struct student));
    FILE* f;
    f = fopen("elever.txt", "r");

    while (fgets(str,sizeof str, f)!=NULL )
    {
        sscanf(str,"%10s %9s %9s %6s %19s %3s %29s", personer[j].personnummer,personer[j].förnamn, personer[j].efternamn, personer[j].gender, personer[j].programmdife, personer[j].age, personer[j].email);
        printf("%10s %9s %9s %6s %19s %3s %29s\n", personer[j].personnummer,personer[j].förnamn, personer[j].efternamn, personer[j].gender, personer[j].programmdife, personer[j].age, personer[j].email);
        j++;
        *x=personer;
    }

    fclose(f);
    //free(personer);
}

int i;
int main()
{
    getchar();
    printf("skriv ny personnummret\n");
    getchar();
    fgets(personer->personnummer,11,stdin);
    printf("skriv förnamn\n");
    getchar();
    fgets(personer->förnamn,50,stdin);
    printf("skriv gender\n");
    fgets(personer->gender,20,stdin);
    printf("skriv programm\n");
    fgets(personer->programmdife,50,stdin);
    printf("skriv ålder\n");
    getchar();
    fgets(personer->age,4,stdin);
    printf("skriv email\n");
    getchar();
    fgets(personer->email,40,stdin);
    // printf("%s %s %s %s %s %s %s", personnummer,förnamn,efternamn,gender,programm,age,email);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you call `malloc`, `j` is still zero, so you'll have room for zero students. Allocate an array that is big enough to hold all students. You could also start small, then grow on demand, either by calling `realloc` or by implementing a linked list of (arrays of) structs. It depends on your requirements.

Comment: @RuudHelderman I get the right number of student and J are the real number of student, because in every line there is a student... the question is how to add +j to the students and insert it in the main function.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated in the comments your `malloc` will return either NULL or a valid pointer to a buffer of 0 bytes, because `j` is 0 when `malloc` is called.

No matter which happens, your code will write to invalid memory.

Then i would strongly recommend to enable warnings (gcc/clang: -W -Wall -Wextra).

One possible solution would be to set `*x = NULL` at the start of your function and use `realloc` to increase the buffer blockwise in the while loop.

In this case the caller has to make sure to use `free` on the memory if it is not used anymore.

Something like this:

```
const int block_size = 16;
int num_allocated = 0;
*x = NULL;
while (your_condition)
{
    if (num_allocated <= j)
    {
        struct student *new_ptr = realloc(*x, (sizeof(struct student) * num_allocated) + (sizeof(struct student) * block_size));
        if (new_ptr == NULL)
        {
            // realloc failed, but ptr is still valid (or NULL if the first call to realloc failed)
            return num_allocated;
        }
        *x = new_ptr;
        num_allocated += block_size;
    }

    // use *x as array of struct student here and fill it
    // for every filled element j has to be increased
}

return number of (usable) elements
```

You can adjust the blocksize for your needs.

If you do not want to waste memory you can also shrink the buffer at the end to the really needed size:

```
struct student *new_ptr = realloc(*x, sizeof(struct student) * num_allocated);
if (new_ptr == NULL)
    return j;
*x = new_ptr;
return j;
```